# [Pydantic+FastAPI+MongoDB]How to initialize Pydantic submodel relationships based on MongoID

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

I have two collections in MongoDB, **users** collection and **mainProjects** collections.

The structure of a document in **users** collections is the following:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65d31d273e4c0f7e973be9e8"
  },
  "name": "MyName",
  "email": "mail@mail.com",
  "user_level": 0
}
```

A document in the **mainProject** collections is:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "65d32dc6f1f6ba0da23b118d"
  },
  "name": "ProjectOne",
  "customer": "Customer1",
  "user_id": {
    "$oid": "65d31d273e4c0f7e973be9e8"
  }
}
```

From these data i build an example API using pydantic models, this is an endpoint API example that **gets a list of mainProjects**:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://connection-string") # your connection string
db = client["database"]
projects = db["mainProject"]

@app.route("/projects/")
def list_projects():

    cursor = projects.find().sort("name")

    return {
        "projects": [MainProjectData(**doc).to_json() for doc in cursor],
    }
```

Earlier I defined User and MainProjectData model as follows:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[PydanticObjectId] = Field(None, alias="_id")
    name: str
    email: str
    user_level: int

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonable_encoder(self, exclude_none=True)

    def to_bson(self):
        data = self.dict(by_alias=True, exclude_none=True)
        if data.get("_id") is None:
            data.pop("_id", None)
        return data

class MainProjectData(BaseModel):
    id: PydanticObjectId
    name: str
    customer: str
    user_id: Optional[PydanticObjectId] = Field(None, alias="user_id")

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonable_encoder(self, exclude_none=True)

    def to_bson(self):
        data = self.dict(by_alias=True, exclude_none=True)
        if data.get("_id") is None:
            data.pop("_id", None)
        return data
```

And the get request on /projects/ api was successful:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "_id": "65d32dc6f1f6ba0da23b118d",
            "customer": "Customer1",
            "name": "ProjectOne",
            "user_id": "65d31d273e4c0f7e973be9e8"
        }
    ]
}
```

**But** I would define MainProjectData model as follows:

```
class MainProjectData(BaseModel):
    id: PydanticObjectId
    name: str
    customer: str
    user: User

    def to_json(self):
        return jsonable_encoder(self, exclude_none=True)

    def to_bson(self):
        data = self.dict(by_alias=True, exclude_none=True)
        if data.get("_id") is None:
            data.pop("_id", None)
        return data
```

And when i call get request on /projects/ obviuously it doesn't work.

I would obtain a response like this, with a nested model/document (in this case User) based on MongoID:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "_id": "65d32dc6f1f6ba0da23b118d",
            "customer": "Customer1",
            "name": "ProjectOne",
            "user": {
                  "_id":"65d31d273e4c0f7e973be9e8"
                  "name": "MyName",
                  "email": "mail@mail.com",
                  "user_level": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I do this? Is it possible to define a submodel for a relationship?

Answer (score 1):

first of all: your title is missleading, you are using Flask and not FastAPI.

About your question: MongoDB gives you the option to do a lookup: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

This requires you to do an aggregation and lookup the user data from the user collection based on the id.

Even though its possible, as far as I understood it, a NoSQL database (eg MongoDB) is not really build to do it this way.